# MariaDB 10.4 Can not use a cte more than once

Tags: sql, mariadb

This is the code you can run,

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=74d081784b301ddfa8bf6d361c586693

```
with date_ranges(`start`, `end`, title) as (
    select  '2021-11-22', '2021-12-21 23:59:59', '1400-09'
    union all
    select '2021-12-22', '2022-01-20 23:59:59', '1400-10'
    union all
    select '2022-02-21', '2022-03-19 23:59:59', '1400-11'
),

     income as (
         select count(*) as input,
                dr.title as month
         from date_ranges dr
                  #join drivers u on u.created_at between dr.start and dr.end
         group by dr.title
     ),
     
          outcome as (
         select count(*) as input,
                ddr.title as month
         from date_ranges ddr
                  #join drivers u on u.created_at between ddr.start and ddr.end
         group by ddr.title
     )


select input, month
from  income i
order by month desc
```

The link above works well but my local database MariaDB 10.4 reports error

> Unknown column 'ddr.title' in 'field list'

Comment: MariaDB has known problems in this area.  Check with a more recent version to see if that has been fixed.  Show the _exact_ version: `SELECT version();`  Quick tests against the latest 10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 10.6 show no issues with your query.  I have an older version of: `10.5.0-MariaDB-log` which produces the error too.  Newer 10.5 does not.

Comment: I have been using a small work-around, by adding a derived column name to the SELECT list inside the CTE reporting a missing column.  See the following change.  Do this for any column reported as unknown: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=21b785651e7991ddb118e75e5839b318

Comment: @JonArmstrong Very nice solution it worked well. Thanks a alot. Please post this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug and has been fixed in recent versions of MariaDB.

The following fiddle shows 10.4.22-MariaDB does not exhibit the issue, but I've verified that 10.5.0-MariaDB-log does produce the error, and 10.3.32-MariaDB, 10.4.22-MariaDB, 10.5.13-MariaDB, 10.6.5-MariaDB do not have this problem.

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=f4f1717a1ff4e4ade47e4db2a2fc92ae)

To work around the bug, we can add an explicit alias (derived column name) in the select list of the common table expression term that is reporting an unknown column.

Notice, for the 3rd select list item of the first UNION term in the `date_ranges` CTE term, I provided a derived column name via `AS title`.  This avoids the bug.  We can do this for any similar columns reported as unknown.

The adjusted SQL:

```
with date_ranges(`start`, `end`, title) as (
    select  '2021-11-22', '2021-12-21 23:59:59', '1400-09' AS title
    union all
    select '2021-12-22', '2022-01-20 23:59:59', '1400-10'
    union all
    select '2022-02-21', '2022-03-19 23:59:59', '1400-11'
),
     income as (
         select count(*) as input,
                dr.title as month
         from date_ranges dr
                  #join drivers u on u.created_at between dr.start and dr.end
         group by dr.title
     ),
     
          outcome as (
         select count(*) as input,
                ddr.title as month
         from date_ranges ddr
                  #join drivers u on u.created_at between ddr.start and ddr.end
         group by ddr.title
     )

select input, month
from  income i
order by month desc
;
```